# Why is my virtual machine still asking a user for password after I deleted its password?

Tags: linux, users, virtual-machine, password

I'm an admin of a virtual machine and I've added a user (let's call it `myuser`) to it. I've also deleted its password (see chain of commands below) at the end of the process, but it still asks for a password (which doesn't exist, so it fails.

Everything is working fine with the ssh keys. This is only happening when the user is running Mac OS (I've done the exact same steps for a user on Ubuntu and it works as expected)..

```
sudo useradd -m myuser
sudo usermod -aG sudo myuser
sudo passwd myuser
(Password is set to "123test")
sudo su myuser
sudo mkdir ~/.ssh
sudo chmod 0700 ~/.ssh
sudo chown myuser:myuser ~/.ssh
sudo touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo chmod 0644 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo vim ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
(Paste public ssh key)
sudo passwd -d -l myuser
```

**Current result:**

User ssh-es into the vm and gets prompted for a password (that doesn't exist, so it fails)

**Expected result:**

User ssh-es into the vm and is taken right into the vm terminal.

Comment: Output of `ssh -v myuser@vm` from the mac where it fails could be useful to see.

Comment: Instead of manually doing all that, try `ssh-copy-id` - it will ensure all the permissions are correct, etc.

Comment: @PederKlingenberg After running with the verbose flag, I see that the issue derives from the fact the user has not permissions ("Permission denied") over their ssh keys. I'll investigate this further as it's late in my timezone. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Check your ssh keys and make sure you are using a modern cipher. I know some Linux distros dropped support for ssh-rsa keys, so the client doesn’t even use them.

Comment: Only the first 4 instances of `sudo` and the last make any sense. The rest of them use root permissions to set the files to be owned by the account calling `sudo`; you might as well have just created them as `myuser` in the first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following Peder's advice, I saw that the user was missing permissions to their ssh folder.

Changing the /var/root/.ssh permission to the user on the mac computer solved the issue.